# Question about my sorting algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, quicksort

i have following  code in c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void qsort5(int a[],int n){
    int i;
    int j;
    if (n<=1)
        return;
    for (i=1;i<n;i++)
        j=0;
    if (a[i]<a[0])
        swap(++j,i,a);
    swap(0,j,a);
    qsort5(a,j);
    qsort(a+j+1,n-j-1);
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}

void swap(int i,int j,int a[])
{
    int t=a[i];
    a[i]=a[j];
    a[j]=t;
}
```

i have problem

```
1>c:\users\dato\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\qsort5\qsort5\qsort5.cpp(13) : error C2780: 'void std::swap(std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xstring(2203) : see declaration of 'std::swap'
1>c:\users\dato\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\qsort5\qsort5\qsort5.cpp(13) : error C2780: 'void std::swap(std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\utility(76) : see declaration of 'std::swap'
1>c:\users\dato\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\qsort5\qsort5\qsort5.cpp(13) : error C2780: 'void std::swap(_Ty &,_Ty &)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\utility(16) : see declaration of 'std::swap'
1>c:\users\dato\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\qsort5\qsort5\qsort5.cpp(14) : error C2780: 'void std::swap(std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xstring(2203) : see declaration of 'std::swap'
1>c:\users\dato\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\qsort5\qsort5\qsort5.cpp(14) : error C2780: 'void std::swap(std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\utility(76) : see declaration of 'std::swap'
1>c:\users\dato\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\qsort5\qsort5\qsort5.cpp(14) : error C2780: 'void std::swap(_Ty &,_Ty &)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\utility(16) : see declaration of 'std::swap'
1>c:\users\dato\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\qsort5\qsort5\qsort5.cpp(16) : error C2661: 'qsort' : no overloaded function takes 2 arguments
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\dato\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\qsort5\qsort5\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
```

please help

Comment: Have you tried putting "void swap(..." *before* "void qsort5(..."?

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with algorithms, let alone quicksort....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`swap` is a function in `std` which must be included by `<iostream>`. When you attempt to make calls to your `swap`, it can't find it (I'll explain in a moment) and instead looks at the `std::sort`, which takes two arguments (hence the first error).

The reason it can't find your `swap` is because it is declared after it is called. You need to either move the definition of your `swap` above that of `qsort5` or forward declare it:

```
void swap(int i,int j,int a[]);

void qsort5(int a[],int n){ 
  ...
```

That tells the compiler that your swap function exists and it will use that when you call `swap` with 3 arguments.

Comment: `std::swap` is in `<algorithm>`, not `<iostream>`.

Comment: Yes, but as I said, it must be included by `<iostream>` otherwise that error wouldn't show. There's nothing stopping those headers from including other headers.

Answer (score 5):

You have to declare your version of `swap` before you use it. Since the compiler did not see a declaration, it used the one it found in the `std` namespace. Also, you mispelled `qsort5` (omitting the 5 in the last line of the function). Again, the compiler found a function with that name (but a different signature) in `std` and complained.

You should either move the entire definition of `swap` to a position before function `qsort5` or insert a declaration

```
void swap(int i,int j,int a[]);
```

before `qsort5`.

Comment: yes but it show me one mistake only
1>c:\users\dato\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\qsort5\qsort5\qsort5.cpp(26) : error C2660: 'qsort' : function does not take 2 arguments

Comment: @davit-datuashvili: The standard library's qsort function requires 4 arguments. You have supplied only two.

Comment: Or more likely, you meant `qsort5` not `qsort`.

Answer (score 1):

do not use `using namespace std;`, is generally bad practice. this brings std::swap into scope, so compiler picks up that swap, rather than yours (since yours is not defined at all this point).

Move definition of your swap before you use it.

Comment: +1 Bringing in "using std" brings a lot of problems like this. If you know the std library good enough you catch these quickly, but using std is often done by beginners that learn to shun it later.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing a brace:

```
for (i=1;i<n;i++)
    j=0;
```

In the above loop, `j` is set to zero a whole bunch of times.  This can be simplified (by you and will be by the compiler) to:

```
j = 0;
```

Otherwise there is a missing set of braces or something else.

Comment: lol, yeah I just saw that also and was tremendously confused :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless this is an exercise, have you considered using `std::sort` instead of reinventing the wheel? Then your error goes away because the `qsort5` function can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You're expecting your swap(int,int,int) function to be called. However if you look at the error, it mentions 'void std::swap(...)'. This is because you are `using namespace std`, and your swap function is declared below qsort5.

So it looks for a swap function, and can only see std:swap. Try putting your swap function above qsort5 so it can see that one as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you perhaps intend to call qsort5 at the end, and call qsort instead?